# VS 2008 C++: How can I copy other files to the output folder?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

In MS Visual Studio 2008, it's very easy to copy non-C# files, such as an XML file, in a C# project to the output folder.  Just add the file to the project, select it in Solution Explorer, then select Properties, and there's a choice named "Copy".  You can choose "Do not copy", "Copy", and "Copy If Newer".

But in C++, it's not so easy, probably because there was never anything similar in earlier versions of Microsoft's compilers.  The only option I have is to add a post-build event with an old-fashioned DOS command line command to copy the file to the target path.  There's no way I know of to compare the dates on the input and target files, if the target file already exists.

I tried adding the files to my C++ project in the same was as I would in a C# project.  The options for the files included a custom build step.  I tried putting the copy command in there, but it didn't work.

Is there some way I don't know about to get the same result as I get in C#: a nice, clean, easy way to specify that a file get copied from the project folder to the output folder if it is newer than the file in the output folder?

Thanks very much!

RobR

Answer (score 1):

In your post-build event, you could use robocopy instead of the basic copy command (it is more intelligent, can somewhat manage file modification dates e.g. `robocopy /xo <...>`)

see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: I did not know about the robocopy command, and thanks very much for telling me about it.  However, it's not going to help me.  Robocopy operates only on folders, and I need it to work on individual files.

And for anyone else reading this, the syntax is "robocopy <source> <destination> [options]"

Comment: Yes it can manage individual files: you can use >robocopy <soource> <dest> <file>

Answer (score 0):

xcopy "source file name" "destination" /D /Y should do it.  When tested in a command window, backslashes instead of forward slashes were required.